# Draw a chain of beads

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote

I would like to reproduce this kind of figure:

[image]

I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve that with TikZ.

My guess is to draw an element composed of a circle + a link and to link this element by specifying only an angle (since the distance is always the same).

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 26):

A very simple proof of concept example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (.5) -- ++(10:2) circle (.5) -- ++(-20:2) circle (.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one could do some very nice tweaks such as building an own style for the lines and circles, but the code above contains at least everything that is needed to reach your goal.

Depending on what you need exactly, it was also very easily possible to automate the generation of such a chain including for example random angles between the beads.

Here's a version using a `\foreach` to specify a list of angles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{bead/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=3pt}}

\draw node[bead] {} (0,0)
\foreach \angle in {10,40,50,-50,0,150,30,-60,45,45,0}
  { -- ++(\angle:1) node[bead] {}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a version with relative angles (**Qrrbrbirlbel** suggested this version in chat and I like it more than the one I initially had):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{bead/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=3pt}}
\def\angle{0}

\draw node[bead] {} (0,0)
\foreach \stepangle[evaluate=\stepangle as \angle using \angle+\stepangle, remember=\angle] in {10,20,-30,-60,135,-20,-30,0}
  { -- ++(\angle:1) node[bead]{}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind non-tikz solutions, I can provide an Asymptote example which lets to construct bead chains in a form like `pos>0>45>-45>90>135`.

Comment: @g.kov I'd encourage answers using different tools.

Comment: @g.kov: It would be nice to have examples of different methods. I request you to make such answers like a tutorial type with more details so that we (atleast I) will start learning. Asymptote is superior in certain aspects.

Comment: I added a version with a `\foreach`. Please feel free to roll-back my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: An `asy` version added.  I tried to make it kind of a tutorial style. If something in the example needs a clarification, please let me know.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, indeed. An example `asy` code added.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the additional edits. They improved my answer a lot.

Comment: @FrançoisBoulogne Nice to hear that the answer helped you. There is a button that looks like a check mark that you can click to [mark the answer as "accepted"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). Also voting on the answers that you consider comprehensive is the way to show your appreciation on this site.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

To fit the original request that a chain is built by specifying only angles,
`Asymptote` provides an operator overloading. An overloaded operator `>`
`pair operator>(pair pos=(0,0), real phi)` takes a position on the left and an angle on the right,
calculates a proper transform (combined rotation and shift) and calls a procedure `bead`
that actually draws the bead with radial shading and a link. Thus the chains are constructed
either as `pos=pos>0>45>-45>90>135` which updates the position, or just `pos>0>45>-45>90>135;` 
`pos>90>90>90;` to draw several branches from the same origin. Note that a numeric comparison
with `>` still works, since it corresponds to a different signature of parameters.
`beads.asy`:

```
size(300,300);
real linkLen=1, linkWidth=2pt; 
real rl=2+linkLen;              // distance between beads
guide g=(1,0)--(1+linkLen,0);   // a link
pen beadColor=orange;
pen linkColor=beadColor;
void bead(transform t){  
  draw(t*g,linkColor+linkWidth);
  radialshade(t*unitcircle,
    beadColor,shift(t)*(-0.4,0.3),0.01
   ,black,shift(t)*(-0.4,0.3),1.5); 
}
pair operator>(pair pos=(0,0), real phi){
  transform t=shift(pos.x,pos.y)*rotate(phi);
  bead(t); // draw a bead with a link
  pos+=rl*(Cos(phi),Sin(phi)); // Sin, Cos - in degrees, sin, cos - in radians
  return pos;
}; 

pair pos=(0,0); // start point

if(exp(1)>pi){ // note that ">" still works the usual way to compare numbers
  // this branch is skipped 
}else{
  pos=pos>0>45>-45>90>135; // draw a bead chain and update the position
  pos>0>45>-45>90>135;     // continue the chain without updating the start position
  beadColor=lightyellow;
  linkColor=lightblue;
  pos>90>90>90;           // draw another branch from saved position, with different colours
}
```

A standalone pdf is produced by `asy -f pdf beads.asy`

**Edit:** This is an inline version, `beads-inline.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\def\asydir{}
\begin{asydef}
// Global Asymptote definitions 
real linkLen=1, linkWidth=2pt; 
real rl=2+linkLen;              // distance between beads
guide link=(1,0)--(1+linkLen,0);   // a link
pen beadColor=orange;
pen linkColor=beadColor;
void bead(transform t){  
  draw(t*link,linkColor+linkWidth);
  radialshade(t*unitcircle,
    beadColor,shift(t)*(-0.4,0.3),0.01
   ,black,shift(t)*(-0.4,0.3),1.5); 
}
pair operator>(pair pos=(0,0), real phi){
  transform t=shift(pos)*rotate(phi);
  bead(t); // draw a bead with a link
  pos+=rl*(Cos(phi),Sin(phi)); // Sin, Cos - in degrees, sin, cos - in radians
  return pos;
}; 
pair pos;
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\hi[1]{\bf Hello \st{Word} #1!}

\center
\captionof{figure}{Example of bead chain building.}
\begin{asy}
  size(150,150);
  pos>0>60>0>70;   
  beadColor=lightyellow;
  pos>0>-60>0>-70;
  pos=  pos>0>0>0>0;     
  label("\textbf{Example}",pos,SE);
\end{asy}

\center
\captionof{figure}{Another example of bead chain building.}
\begin{asy}
  size(150,150);
  beadColor=lightyellow;
  linkColor=lightblue;
  pos=pos>90>42>0>0>0>0>0>0>-130;   
  label(
     "\parbox{8cm}{"
     "The following command \texttt{\textbackslash hi} is defined \\"
     +"in the main \LaTeX\ document:\\"
     "\hi{\LaTeX}}"
     ,pos);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf beads-inline.tex`. The result looks like

[image]

For more details consult the manual at: [asymptote development page at sourceforge](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/asymptote.pdf)
or, in case if you happened to be a lucky `TeX Live` user,
just type `texdoc asymptote`.

Comment: Thank you for `Asymptote` side of graphics typesetting.

Comment: @texenthusiast: Perhaps, the `Asymptote` just needs more ready-to-use templates to become more popular.

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to compile this from within the .tex file?! Also, (I was wondering looking at your previous answers) how do you find out the coordinates? Is there any short cut?. It will be nice if you add the links to reference/learning material. +1 indeed.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: The main documentation is at `http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/asymptote.pdf`.
If you mean the bead coordinates, in the example they are stored in `pos` variable and update happens in a line `pos+=rl*(Cos(phi),Sin(phi));`.

Answer (score 13):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\X(#1){#1}
\def\Y(#1){3+2*sin(#1)}

\psset{algebraic,showpoints,dotscale=3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(7,6)
    \psparametricplot[plotpoints=10]{-0.5}{6.5}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

### *Animation*

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\X(#1){#1}
\def\Y(#1){3+2*sin(#1)}

\psset{algebraic,showpoints,dotscale=3}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=2+1}{21}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(7,6)
    \psparametricplot[plotpoints=\i]{-0.5}{6.5}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

### *The latest edit*

If you need equally-spaced beads, see the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(8,3)
    \psStartPoint(0,0)
    \psforeach{\i}{10,40,50,-50,0,150,30,-60,45,45,0}{\psVector[arrows=-*](1;\i)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(8,3)
    \pnode(0,0){A}
    \psforeach{\i}{10,40,50,-50,0,150,30,-60,45,45,0}{
    \pnode[!1 \i\space PtoC](A){B}
    \pscircle*(B){4pt}
    \psline(A)(B)
    \pnode(B){A}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the PSTricks equivalent to the `\foreach` solution by [Benedikt Bauer/Gonzalo Medina](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/106197/3), i.e. fixed width and specified angles?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: well done!

Comment: There is no more technique with `\pspolylineticks` which is very sophisticated but its documentation is really confusing to grasp.

Comment: The second code does not work me. It gives the following error:
`Undefined control sequence. ...lot[plotpoints=10]{-0.5}{6.5}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

Another TikZ solution that uses <s>ducks</s> turtles! `:)`

The `turtle` library is well-explained in its own chapter in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), chapter 54/59 “Turtle Graphics Library”:

> This little library defines some keys to create simple turtle graphics in the tradition of the Logo programming language. These commands are mostly for fun, but they can also be used for more “serious” business.

#### Keys

- `bead node` style: a node style for the beads (→ [Benedikt Bauer’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106197/16595));
- `bead` style: an `insert path` that makes it easy to include a bead node, it accepts one optional parameter to customize the bead node;
- `bead path` style: this is a `to path` that includes a `bead node` at the start coordinate and your usual line to `--` to the target coordinate;
- `turtle/beads` style: this install all necessary styles inside the `turtle` key:

  - the `how` style is set to the `bead path` style, and
  - the starting direction is set by turning the turtle to the right

Now we would be able to say

```
\draw (0,0) [turtle={beads, right=10, forward, left=20, forward, …}];
```

and so on and it would work quite well, but the lazy turtle just wants to know the (relative) directions it has to head.

This is why I defined an additional `turn and step` style in the `turtle` path.
When used with the `.list` handler we can process a comma-delimited list of (relative) angles very easily:

```
\draw (0,0) [turtle={beads,turn and step/.list={10,20,-30,-60,135,-20,-30,0}}] [bead];
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\tikzset{
    bead node/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=3pt},
    bead path/.style={to path={ [bead] -- (\tikztotarget)}},
    bead/.style={insert path={node[bead node]{}}},
    turtle/beads/.style={how/.style={bead path},right},
    turtle/turn and step/.style={left=#1,forward}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[turtle/distance=1cm]
\draw (0,0) [turtle={beads,turn and step/.list={10,20,-30,-60,135,-20,-30,0}}] [bead];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question for me because `tkz-graph` is a possibility o draw this kind of graph but  I created the possibility to add vertices with polar coordinates, I need to use the origin and not the last vertex. So I need to find a trick to build the graph.

```
\documentclass[margin=.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Art]% Init the graph and choice a style
\SetVertexNoLabel% no label
\Vertex{A} 
\foreach \a in {45,10,30,-20,0,-60,-40,-45,-10,-90,+20,0,60,-40}{%
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]% polar from the last vertex
    \Vertex[a=\a , d=1 cm]{B}
    \Edge[style={thick,double=black,double distance=1pt}](A)(B) 
    \pgfnoderename{A}{B}% rename the node, useful macro here
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Possible to get a shorter code:

```
\newcommand{\newVertex}[1]{%
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
    \Vertex[a=#1 , d=1 cm]{B} 
\end{scope}    
}
```

and

```
\foreach \a in {45,10,30,-20,0,-60,-40,-45,-10,-90,+20,0,60,-40}{%
    \newVertex{\a}
    \Edge[style={thick,double=black,double distance=1pt}](A)(B) 
    \pgfnoderename{A}{B}
}
```