# drawing a cluster of gears

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can draw individuals gears like the following but I was unable to align them in the following manner. Could you help?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,  latexsym, amscd, amsthm}

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
  [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1]  (0:#2)  arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt]
             -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
}}      

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick] \gear{16}{1.6}{1.8}{10}{2};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code of the individual gears you can draw?

Comment: Yes, I have added the tex codes.

Comment: Hint: to format a **selection** of text as code, simply press the `{ }` button at the top of the editing field.

Comment: I use draw like this but not work: \draw (11,1) node {\gear{16}{1.6}{1.8}{10}{2}};

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106679/how-to-draw-a-chain-of-gears, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/creating-gears-in-tikz?lq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should get you started:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {   [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1] (0:#2) arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
    }
}      

\begin{document}

% given
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rOne}{1.6}% inner radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nOne}{16}% num teeth
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nTwo}{24}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothHeight}{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothFall}{1}% degrees where radius drops from inner to outer
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aOneTwo}{120}% angle from first to second

% computed
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rTwo}{\rOne*\nTwo/\nOne}% via equating tooth lengths
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ROne}{\rOne+\toothHeight}% outer radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RTwo}{\rTwo+\toothHeight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dOne}{(360/\nOne-\toothFall)/2}% degrees for a tooth; here inner deg = outer deg
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dTwo}{(360/\nTwo-\toothFall)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distOneTwo}{\rOne+\rTwo+\toothHeight+0.05}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] \gear{\nOne}{\rOne}{\ROne}{\dOne}{\toothFall};
    \draw[thick, shift={(\aOneTwo:\distOneTwo)}, rotate=5.5] \gear{\nTwo}{\rTwo}{\RTwo}{\dTwo}{\toothFall};
    \draw[-latex] (\aOneTwo:\rOne/2) -- (\aOneTwo:\rOne);
    \draw[-latex, shift={(\aOneTwo:\distOneTwo)}] (\aOneTwo+180:\RTwo/2) -- (\aOneTwo+180:\RTwo);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** You can chain them together quite easily if you use coordinates to refer to the centers of the gears.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {   [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1] (0:#2) arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
    }
}      

\begin{document}

% given
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rOne}{1.6}% inner radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nOne}{17}% num teeth
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nTwo}{23}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nThree}{19}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothHeight}{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothFall}{1}% degrees where radius drops from inner to outer
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aOneTwo}{120}% angle from first to second
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aTwoThree}{20}% angle from first to second

% computed
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rTwo}{\rOne*\nTwo/\nOne}% via equating tooth lengths
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rThree}{\rOne*\nThree/\nOne}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ROne}{\rOne+\toothHeight}% outer radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RTwo}{\rTwo+\toothHeight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RThree}{\rThree+\toothHeight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dOne}{(360/\nOne-\toothFall)/2}% degrees for a tooth; here inner deg = outer deg
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dTwo}{(360/\nTwo-\toothFall)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dThree}{(360/\nThree-\toothFall)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distOneTwo}{\rOne+\rTwo+\toothHeight+0.05}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distTwoThree}{\rTwo+\rThree+\toothHeight+0.05}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(\aOneTwo:\distOneTwo)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(\aTwoThree:\distTwoThree)$);  

    \draw[thick, rotate=9] node[align=center] {$\alpha$ \\ \nOne\ Teeth} \gear{\nOne}{\rOne}{\ROne}{\dOne}{\toothFall} ;
    \draw[thick, shift={(B)}, rotate=7] node[align=center] {$\beta$ \\ \nTwo\ Teeth} \gear{\nTwo}{\rTwo}{\RTwo}{\dTwo}{\toothFall};
    \draw[thick, shift={(C)}, rotate=8] node[align=center] {$\gamma$ \\ \nThree\ Teeth} \gear{\nThree}{\rThree}{\RThree}{\dThree}{\toothFall};

    \draw[-latex, very thick] (\aOneTwo:\rOne/2) -- (\aOneTwo:\rOne);
    \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(B)}] (\aOneTwo+180:\rTwo/2) -- (\aOneTwo+180:\rTwo);

    \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(B)}] (\aTwoThree:\rTwo/2) -- (\aTwoThree:\rTwo);
    \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(C)}] (\aTwoThree+180:\rThree/2) -- (\aTwoThree+180:\rThree);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** Just for fun, here's a little animation made from it. After producing the `.pdf`, it used ImageMagick to convert it:
`convert -loop 0 -delay 2 -density 250 -dispose previous richard.pdf gear.gif`

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc}

\newcommand{\gear}[5]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {   [rotate=(\i-1)*360/#1] (0:#2) arc (0:#4:#2) {[rounded corners=0.5pt] -- (#4+#5:#3)  arc (#4+#5:360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (360/#1:#2)
    }
}      

\begin{document}

% given
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rOne}{1.6}% inner radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nOne}{17}% num teeth
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nTwo}{23}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nThree}{19}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothHeight}{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\toothFall}{1}% degrees where radius drops from inner to outer
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aOneTwo}{120}% angle from first to second
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aTwoThree}{20}% angle from first to second

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numFrames}{50}% number of individual pictures

% computed
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rTwo}{\rOne*\nTwo/\nOne}% via equating tooth lengths
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rThree}{\rOne*\nThree/\nOne}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ROne}{\rOne+\toothHeight}% outer radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RTwo}{\rTwo+\toothHeight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RThree}{\rThree+\toothHeight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dOne}{(360/\nOne-\toothFall)/2}% degrees for a tooth; here inner deg = outer deg
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dTwo}{(360/\nTwo-\toothFall)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dThree}{(360/\nThree-\toothFall)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distOneTwo}{\rOne+\rTwo+\toothHeight+0.05}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\distTwoThree}{\rTwo+\rThree+\toothHeight+0.05}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rotOne}{(360/\nOne/\numFrames}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rotTwo}{(360/\nTwo/\numFrames}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rotThree}{(360/\nThree/\numFrames}

\foreach \frame in {1,...,\numFrames}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(\aOneTwo:\distOneTwo)$);
        \coordinate (C) at ($(B)+(\aTwoThree:\distTwoThree)$);  

        \draw[white] (-4.5,-1.9) rectangle (4,7);

        \draw[thick, rotate=9+\frame*\rotOne] node[align=center] {$\alpha$ \\ \nOne\ Teeth} \gear{\nOne}{\rOne}{\ROne}{\dOne}{\toothFall} ;
        \draw[thick, shift={(B)}, rotate=7-\frame*\rotTwo] node[align=center] {$\beta$ \\ \nTwo\ Teeth} \gear{\nTwo}{\rTwo}{\RTwo}{\dTwo}{\toothFall};
        \draw[thick, shift={(C)}, rotate=8+\frame*\rotThree] node[align=center] {$\gamma$ \\ \nThree\ Teeth} \gear{\nThree}{\rThree}{\RThree}{\dThree}{\toothFall};

        \draw[-latex, very thick] (\aOneTwo:\rOne/2) -- (\aOneTwo:\rOne);
        \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(B)}] (\aOneTwo+180:\rTwo/2) -- (\aOneTwo+180:\rTwo);

        \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(B)}] (\aTwoThree:\rTwo/2) -- (\aTwoThree:\rTwo);
        \draw[-latex, very thick, shift={(C)}] (\aTwoThree+180:\rThree/2) -- (\aTwoThree+180:\rThree);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You can also play around with it and [animate it.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ETplK.gif)

Comment: There is a bulb on the upper right corner.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: That, unfortunately, is not due to my brilliance, but rather some feature of Adobe Reader.

Comment: I can not draw this. Could you help to complete the figure?

Comment: @Thumbolt: Yes. Please see the edit (in a few minutes).