# TikZ: Combining multiple paths in and outside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, paths, foreach

I am trying to generate a path from a list of directions (as seen on the numpad). The coordinates are generated correctly, but because I use multiple call to \path the arrowheads are drawn on each segment. How do I change this code to only draw the starting arrowhead on the first segment and the ending arrowhead on the last segment? I have unsuccessfully tried to have one \path outside the \foreach and only coordinates inside.

edit: It should work for any arrow shape passed in the optional argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\directedPath}[5][]
{
  \edef\start{#2}
  \edef\stop{#3}
  \edef\step{#4}
  \edef\directions{#5}
  \coordinate (c0) at (\start);
  \foreach [var=\dir, count=\cur] in \directions
  {
    % current coordinate dx
    \pgfmathparse{(1-(1-1/sqrt(2))*mod(\dir, 2))*\step*(mod(\dir-1, 3)-1)}
    \edef\dx{\pgfmathresult}
    % current coordinate dy
    \pgfmathparse{(1-(1-1/sqrt(2))*mod(\dir, 2))*\step*(div(\dir-1, 3)-1)}
    \edef\dy{\pgfmathresult}
    % previous coordinate index
    \pgfmathparse{int(\cur - 1)}
    \xdef\prev{\pgfmathresult}
    % current coordinate
    \coordinate (c\cur) at ($(c\prev) + (\dx, \dy)$);
    % draw partial path
    \ifnum \cur>1
      \path [#1] (c\prev) -- (c\cur);
    \fi
  }
  \path [#1] (\start) -- (c1);
  \path [#1] (c\cur) -- (\stop);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=green] (Start) at (0, 0) {Start};
  \node [draw=red] (End) at (5, 2) {End};
  \directedPath[draw=black, >->]{Start}{End}{1.0}{3,6,9,8,7,8,9,6,3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick fix would be removing `>->` and using `\path [#1,>-] (\start) -- (c1);  \path [#1,->] (c\cur) -- (\stop);`

Comment: While this solves the problem as stated, it is not what I intended. I should have been more specific. I want it to accept the arrow type as part of the optional argument, making it work for any type of arrowhead.

Comment: How about making the entire path a single `\path` command?  Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: You can provide the start and end arrow types as separate keys.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Absolutely. That would probably be the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no question that this need to be done in one single path but you can do this quite easily with the `turtle` library.

Simply define a direction (and a factor) for every digit.

As the `direction` key only turns the “turtle”, also include the `forward` key which includes a `to[/tikz/turtle/how]` path to the relative coordinate in `direction` and the given `distance`, i.e.

```
to[/tikz/turtle/how] ++ (<direction>:<distance>)
```

The `Start` and `End` simply insert a `move to` to `(Start)` and a (final?) `line to` to `(End)` (or whatever the `how` style is currently).

Of course, you can use the math from your question in the setup of the digit styles, but this is just faster (for TikZ and to write up).

I opted for a grid-like output which needs the factor `sqrt(2)` for the diagonal directions. Set this factor to `1` to get the same distance as in your question. (I also changed the example a little bit to get a symmetrical result.)

I have created and used an auxiliary style for the setup, marked by an `@`. It may also preferable to simply define this style in a `/aux` path as we won’t use it again or really need it in the `/tikz` path.

This also makes it easy to set all factors to `1` by omitting the value of the `forward` key (the default is `/tikz/turtle/distance` anyway if no value is given), i.e.

```
@setup turtle digits/.style n args={3}{
  /tikz/turtle/#1/.style={
    /tikz/turtle/direction=#2,
    /tikz/turtle/forward}}
```

(There is no real reason to set the value of the `forward` key to a fixed distance as it would be more consistent to change the `distance` value.)

If you suddenly feel that the keys shouldn’t be called `1`, `2`, … `9` but `1 step`, `2 step`, … `9 step` you simply add  `step` after `#1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\tikzset{
  @setup turtle digits/.style n args={3}{
    /tikz/turtle/#1/.style={
      /tikz/turtle/direction=#2,
      /tikz/turtle/forward={#3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/turtle/distance}}}},
  @setup turtle digits={1}{south west}{1.41421},
  @setup turtle digits={2}{south}     {1},
  @setup turtle digits={3}{south east}{1.41421},
  @setup turtle digits={4}{left}      {1},
  @setup turtle digits={6}{right}     {1},
  @setup turtle digits={7}{north west}{1.41421},
  @setup turtle digits={8}{north}     {1},
  @setup turtle digits={9}{north east}{1.41421},
  turtle/.cd,
    Start/.style={/tikz/insert path={(#1)}},
    End/.style={/tikz/insert path={to[/tikz/turtle/how] (#1)}},
    Start/.default=Start,
    End/.default=End,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=green] (Start) at (0, 1) {Start};
  \node [draw=red]   (End)   at (5, 2) {End};
  \draw [draw=black, >->] [turtle={Start, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, End}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### with the factors

[image]

#### without the factors

[image]

Comment: I actually like the grid-like path more, even though it doesn't behave exactly like in my example. I assume you have the source for that as well, could you possibly provide it?

Comment: @Linus I have updated my answer including the code for the grid-like approach. It is pretty much the same except for the factor. It shouldn’t be hard to customize this for different problems.

Comment: @Qrrbrirlbel Trying to understand how this example works. What exactly does "@setup" do?

Comment: @Linus I have updated my answer. `@setup turtle digits` is simply an auxiliary style that makes it possible to define the styles `1` through `9` consistently. You can check out two other answers of mine that uses the `turtle` library [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107189) or at least the basic principle behind it [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107794).

Comment: Thief, thief!  Qrrbrbirlbel!  We hates it, we hates it forever!!  (That's for stealing my green tick.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a single path version:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123997/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\directedPath}[5][]
{
  \coordinate (c0) at (#2);
  \path (c0)
  \foreach [var=\dir,count=\cur] in {#5}
  {
    ++({(1-(1-1/sqrt(2))*mod(\dir, 2))*#4*(mod(\dir-1, 3)-1)},{(1-(1-1/sqrt(2))*mod(\dir, 2))*#4*(div(\dir-1, 3)-1)}) coordinate (c\cur)
  };
  \path[#1] (#2) -- (c1) \foreach [var=\dir,count=\cur] in {#5}
  {
    -- (c\cur)
  } -- (#3);
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw=green] (Start) at (0, 0) {Start};
  \node [draw=red] (End) at (5, 2) {End};
  \directedPath[draw=black, >->]{Start}{End}{1.0}{3,6,9,8,7,8,9,6,3}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The two foreach loops are because the path starts and ends at non-zero sized nodes, but the displacements are relative to the node centres.  In the second path, there's an extra `(c1)` which is needed due to the issue raised at [Draw a path between many nodes using foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75146/86).  For an alternative solution, see the answers there.

[image: Single path with foreach]